# Formula parsing string, sometimes by comma sometimes not

Tags: formula, formula-field

I have a string that contains one or more email addresses, for example:

> email1@example.com, email2@example.com

I want to select just the first email address, which is doable with something like

```
LEFT(EmailString(FIND(",",EmailString,1)-1)
```

That formula searches for a comma, but what do I do when there is only one value and no comma? If the email is simply `email1@example.com` then that formula throws an error on the find. Is there a better formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can incorporate the `IF` and `CONTAINS` functions here:

```
IF(
    NOT(CONTAINS(EmailString, ',')),
    EmailString, /*your existing formula here*/
)
```

Basically, if there is no comma, just use the value, otherwise use the formula you already have.

Comment: OP could also append a comma to EmailString  and use orig formula